# Shorter way to render certain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

In a view I would like to render the amount of people living in a person's house. 
The follow code works, but I believe there is a shorter and better way to write the code.

```
<% if current_user.family_size == 1 %>
   <li><%= current_user.family_size %> person</li>
<% else %>
   <li><%= current_user.family_size %> people</li>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pluralize method:

```
<li><%= pluralize(current_user.family_size, 'person') %></li>
```

UPDATE:

If there is a need for pluralized noun without a count, use:

```
'person'.pluralize(2)   #=> 'people'
```